# Removing punctuation using spaCy; AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

Currently I'm using the following code to lemmatize and calculate TF-IDF values for some text data using spaCy:

```
lemma = []

for doc in nlp.pipe(df['col'].astype('unicode').values, batch_size=9844,
                        n_threads=3):
    if doc.is_parsed:
        lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc if not n.lemma_.is_punct | n.lemma_ != "-PRON-"])
    else:
        lemma.append(None)

df['lemma_col'] = lemma

vect = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer()
lemmas = df['lemma_col'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
vect = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer()
features = vect.fit_transform(lemmas)

feature_names = vect.get_feature_names()
dense = features.todense()
denselist = dense.tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame(denselist, columns=feature_names)
df = pd.DataFrame(denselist, columns=feature_names)
lemmas = pd.concat([lemmas, df])
df= pd.concat([df, lemmas])
```

I need to strip out proper nouns, punctuation, and stop words but am having some trouble doing that within my current code.  I've read some [documentation](https://nicschrading.com/project/Intro-to-NLP-with-spaCy/) and [other resources](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/04/natural-language-processing-made-easy-using-spacy-%E2%80%8Bin-python/), but am now running into an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e924639f7822> in <module>()
      7     if doc.is_parsed:
      8         tokens.append([n.text for n in doc])
----> 9         lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc if not n.lemma_.is_punct or n.lemma_ != "-PRON-"])
     10         pos.append([n.pos_ for n in doc])
     11     else:

<ipython-input-21-e924639f7822> in <listcomp>(.0)
      7     if doc.is_parsed:
      8         tokens.append([n.text for n in doc])
----> 9         lemma.append([n.lemma_ for n in doc if not n.lemma_.is_punct or n.lemma_ != "-PRON-"])
     10         pos.append([n.pos_ for n in doc])
     11     else:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_punct'
```

Is there an easier way to strip this stuff out of the text, without having to drastically change my approach?

Full code available [here](https://github.com/LizMGagne/TIP_code/blob/master/TIP%20Stuff%20(8).ipynb).

Answer (score 20):

From what I can see, your main problem here is actually quite simple: `n.lemma_` returns a string, not a `Token` object. So it doesn't have an `is_punct` attribute. I think what you were looking for here is `n.is_punct` (whether the *token* is punctuation).

If you want to do this more elegantly, check out spaCy's new [custom processing pipeline components](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) (requires v2.0+). This lets you wrap your logic in a function which is run automatically when you call `nlp()` on your text. You could even take this one step further, and add a [custom attribute](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes) to your `Doc` – for example, `doc._.my_stripped_doc` or `doc._.pd_columns` or something. The advantage here is that you can keep using spaCy's performant, built-in data structures like the `Doc` (and its views `Token` and `Span`) as the "single source of truth" of your application. This way, no information is lost and you'll always keep a reference to the original document – which is also very useful for debugging.

Comment: Is there any way I can remove punctuation from the middle of a spaCy Token ? For e.g. there is a token "hello-world" how can I convert it into "hello world" ? I have referred https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes

Answer (score 4):

as you are using spacy use this function to remove punctuation .

```
df["newcolname"] = df.column name(onwhich yoy want to remove stopword).apply(lambda text: 
                                      " ".join(token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text) 
                                               if not token.is_punct)
df["puncfree"] = df.review.apply(lambda text: 
                                      " ".join(token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text) 
                                               if not token.is_punct))
```

for convince and better understanding i am posting my code that i used to remove punctuation

"review" is column name i want to remove punctuation from.

Answer (score 3):

Building off @khawaja-fahad-shafi's answer, I created the following pattern, where `data` is a pandas DataFrame and `text` is a field of strings.  I originally posted this as a comment not an answer, but the formatting was off.  Hope it's helpful for someone.

```
import pandas
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

(data["text"]
 .apply(lambda text: " "
        .join(token.lemma_ for token in nlp(text) if
              not token.is_punct
              and not token.is_currency
              and not token.is_digit
              and not token.is_oov
              and not token.is_space
              and not token.is_stop
              and not token.like_num
              and not token.pos_ == "PROPN")))
```

Comment: `token.is_punct` is written twice

Comment: Good catch @FaridAlijani.  Just edited to remove the duplicated portion.