# SpaCy - Split the neuralcoref results into sentences

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using the [neuralcoref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) library for coreference resolution. It works on top of the Spacy library. I get it working as by the documentation.

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_resolved) # My sister has a dog. My sister loves a dog.
```

What I want to do is to split the coref_resolved attribute into sentences and remove punctuations. I don't know how to do it without running it through another NLP annotation, like so:

```
 doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
 doc2 = nlp(doc1._.coref_resolved)
 print(list(doc2.sents)) # [My sister has a dog., My sister loves a dog.]
```

Next, I would need to also remove punctuations. How can I do this without running a single sentence through two different NLP pipelines? I want my result to look like:

```
["My sister has a dog", "My sister loves a dog"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an idea how to install neuralcoref? I tried on Win10, but to no avail.

Comment: I got it working by running the following commands:

git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
cd neuralcoref
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e .
pip install spacy==2.3.2
python -m spacy download en

Comment: I only could install neuralcoref in Linux. So, 1) `doc1._.coref_resolved` is a Unicode string, and 2) it is really easier to just run sentence split using a second call to `nlp` rather than trying to drill into token/span structure of the mentions. Removing punctuation is a known issue, see [Removing punctuation using spaCy; AttribueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144311/removing-punctuation-using-spacy-attribueerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc1._.coref_resolved` is of `str` type so you may wish to process it towards your desired output as:

```
import string

sents = doc1._.coref_resolved.split(". ")
sents_wo_punct = []
for sent in sents:
    sents_wo_punct.append(sent.translate(str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)))
print(sents_wo_punct)
```

---

```
['My sister has a dog', 'My sister loves a dog']
```